# Ext.form.Basic, object creation fail

Tags: extjs4.1

I want to use setValues() method, which can set all values togather, as I have more than 35 control on form.
Problem is, setValues() method exist under Ext.form.Basic and I can not invoke that by creating object of Ext.form.Panel. So I tried creating object of Ext.form.basic, but it raise error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'".
How to create object of 'Ext.form.Basic'.

Comment: Have you tried `formPanel.getForm().setValues(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getForm()` method of your `Ext.form.Panel` to get the `Ext.form.Basic` object.  Then you can call `getValues()`.

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel, { ... });
formPanel.getForm().setValues({ ... });
```